# Typescript with Styled-Component Error: Type 'GlobalStylesProps' has no properties in common with type '{ theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components, storybook

I'm passing a props inside GlobalStyles (in the preview.js file of the storybook) to remove a background from the default theme, it's ok working, it removes the background. But I'm getting this error from Typescript :

Type 'GlobalStylesProps' has no properties in common with type '{ theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; }'.

I'm using nextjs, typscript and storybook.

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.12",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "plop": "^3.1.1",
    "polished": "^4.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "styled-icons": "^10.46.0",
    "styled-media-query": "^2.1.2"
  },
```

**.storybook/preview.js:**

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import GlobalStyles from 'styles/global'
import theme from 'styles/theme'

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles removeBg />
      <Story />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
]
```

**styles/global.ts:**

```
import {
  createGlobalStyle,
  css,
  DefaultTheme,
  GlobalStyleComponent
} from 'styled-components'

type GlobalStylesProps = {
  removeBg?: boolean
}

const GlobalStyles: GlobalStyleComponent<
  GlobalStylesProps,
  DefaultTheme
> = createGlobalStyle`
  ${({ theme, removeBg }) => css`
    html {
      font-size: 62.5%;
    }

    body {
      font-family: ${theme.font.family};
      font-size: ${theme.font.sizes.medium};

      ${!removeBg &&
      css`
        background-color: ${theme.colors.mainBg};
      `}
    }
  `}
`

export default GlobalStyles
```

**styles/theme.ts:**

```
export default {
  colors: {
    mainBg: '#06092B'
  }
}
```

Has anyone gone through something similar?

thanks for any help

For the GlobalStyleComponent I passed the GlobalStylesProps as the first object and also the DefaultTheme , but the error continues

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

Put *theme: DefaultTheme* inside **styles/global.ts**

```
type GlobalStyleProps = {
  theme: DefaultTheme
  removeBg?: boolean
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).